# Multi dimensional Variants for efficient writing in excel worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a program where I collect some rows from a sheet depending on some conditions, then paste the selected rows in a new sheet.

I was wondering if it is possible to reduce the number of times I have to write the selected rows in the new sheet. Right now I am doing it row by row.

For simplicity, I am creating a hypothetical example. Suppose I have a variant array 'table' as follows:

```
Dim table(100) as Variant
For i = 0 To 100
  table(i)= Range(Range("A1").offset(i,0), Range("A1").Offset(i, 8)).Value
Next i
```

Now if I want to paste the values in a new sheet, I am doing:

```
Worksheets(2).activate    
For i = 0 To 100
Range(Range("A1").offset(i,0), Range("A1").Offset(i, 8)).Value = table(i)
Next i
```

Is it possible to to do the pasting in a single step? I was wondering because, I have observed that if I create a multidimensional variant such as

```
Dim data(100,8) as Variant
data = Range("A1:I100").Value
```

then, I can paste this as a single step in the new sheet

```
Worksheets(2).activate   
Range("A1:I100").Value = data;
```

The problem in my program is that, I am inserting one dimensional horizontal ranges into a variant array one by one depending on some condition. So as shown initially, I am ending up with a variant array like 'table'. Can it be possible to somehow convert this table into a standard 2 dimensional array like 'data', shown above so that I can paste it using a single step in the new sheet?

I am relatively new in VBA with some experience in C++. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `(100)` specifies the upperbound of the afray and the upperbound of the For loop is inclusive. Your array thus has 101 elements and the for loop loops 101 times. (The lower bound of the array is determined by the `Option Base` statement and is normally 0.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly ran into the annoying fact that even 1-dimensional ranges copy to 2-dimensional variant arrays. The following function takes an array of such unnecessarily 2-dimensional arrays and consolidates it to a single 2-dimensional array that can be directly pasted (in your case -- you can paste consolidate(table)):

```
Function consolidate(arrays As Variant) As Variant
'assumes that each entry of arrays is a 2-dimensional array of the form 1 to 1, 1 to n
'with the same n for each entry
    Dim block As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lb As Long, ub As Long, n As Long, j As Long
    lb = LBound(arrays)
    ub = UBound(arrays)
    n = UBound(arrays(lb), 2)
    ReDim block(lb To ub, 1 To n)
    For i = lb To ub
        For j = 1 To n
            block(i, j) = arrays(i)(1, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    consolidate = block
End Function
```

Comment: I answered your specific question -- but Paul Oglivie's revised answer might be a better answer to your specific problem. If *all* you want to do is paste some but not all rows of data from one sheet to another sheet then it would be better to bypass the middleman and directly paste the ranges as you identify them (perhaps with screenupdating turned off). My approach, involving as it does nested for-loops, would only make sense if your code needs to do something with these values before pasting.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Range(Range("A1").Offset(0, 0), Range("A1").Offset(100, 8)).Copy
Worksheets(2).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I.e. select everything you want to copy, active the other woksheet, then paste the values there.

Comment: Thanks Paul. But actually I am facing a different problem. In my program,I have a worksheet with some data. I scroll down each row and depending on some condition, I selectively add some horizontal ranges into a variant array. So the data that needs to be copied is not sequential. 

The example of 'table' was just a hypothetical case. So in my program,after selectively adding some rows into a variant, I end up with a variant of a similar type like 'table'.  Now with such kind of variant, I am forced to paste it row by row in the new sheet

Comment: "I have a worksheet with some data. I scroll down each row and depending on some condition, I..." _copy each row immediately to the other sheet._ So prevent the use of the array altogether and instead, copy&paste directly.

Comment: Yes..I thought about it. But the number of columns wont be the same when I'll be posting it in the new sheet, although same across all records. I'll be performing some adjustments depending upon the criteria used for selection and then pasting them.  Actually I can still do this by copying directly but there is a very small chance that the data can be used as an argument by some other function. So wanted to store it in some container. But yes copying directly and including the manipulation in the first loop itself would make sense.

Comment: You can use an intemediate sheet: copy the rows to the inermediate sheet, then emove the columns you don;t want, then copy the intermediate sheet to the final sheet (assuming the final sheet has headers and lots of other things you don;t want to upset with removing columns).